# Putting tab content in the middle

Tags: html, css

Hi guys for some reason i cant move my tab and all the content in the middle.

I have tried things like `margin: 0 auto;` , setting a `width` etc but nothing has worked

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jganfLua/)

```
.tab-group{
    margin: 0 auto;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to center all the tab content:

```
.tab-content {
  text-align: center;
}
```

**Edit:**

I misunderstood your initial question. You'll also want to do this:

```
.tab-group li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Lastly, you might notice a small gap between your tabs after adding the `inline-block`. A quick fix for that is to remove all the closing `</li>`s in your `<ul>` except the last one. This ensures no white space will mess with your spacing when using `inline-block`.

```
<ul class="tab-group">
  <li class="tab active"><a href="#signup">3D</a>
  <li class="tab"><a href="#login">REF</a></li>
</ul>
```

If removing the closing tag bothers you (it bothers some people), you can always just remove all the white space manually.

```
<ul class="tab-group"><li class="tab active"><a href="#signup">3D</a></li><li class="tab"><a href="#login">REF</a></li></ul>
```

I'm a fan of the first method :)

Comment: Ah that works for the text however i need it for the tabs is well